# How to exclude a range of data points by index from a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, slice

how can i slice a dataframe to exclude a range of index?

```
    A     B     C     D
1   1     4     6     1
2   4     5     4     1
3   7     3     4     1
.
.
.
98  1     1     2     4
99  6     3     4     6
100 4     5     3     6
```

What is the easiest way to remove say 10:20 indexed data points from this dataframe?

Comment: `df[-c(10:20), ]`

Comment: That worked. I had tried something similar earlier but it didnt work. Maybe there was some syntax error. Post it as an answer, i'll accept it as an answer Ronak.

Comment: Thanks but I think this has been rightly marked as duplicate since this has been asked before.